# Flutter package: Not able to read file from assets

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-file

I have few resources in my flutter package 'packme' which is used by multiple apps.

There are some resources(contains images and PDF files) which are required to be loaded within my packages and served to app in bytes. I am trying multiple ways to load data but not successful.

I have added file to `packme/assets/images/test-image-01.png` as well `packme/lib/assets/images/test-image-01.png`

packme/pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:

  # To add assets to your package, add an assets section, like this:
   assets:
     - assets/images/
     - lib/assets/images/
```

Having following function to test path exists or not, prints false for all:

```
void checkPaths() {
  List<String> images = [
    'packages/packme/assets/images/test-image-01.png',
    'images/test-image-01.png',
    'lib/assets/images/test-image-01.png',
  ];

  for (var image in images) {
    print(
        "fileExists? $image ${File(image).existsSync()}"); //Prints false for each file
   }
```

What is the way to load bytes data for file from `assets` or `lib` from a package?

I hev checked multiple posts and flutter-docs but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly `File('packages/packme/assets/images/test-image-01.png').existSync()` is giving `false` but following code works fine:

```
ByteData byteData = await rootBundle.load('packages/packme/assets/images/test-image-01.png');
  return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

Can anyone reflect on this?

Comment: File is used to load files from app's private storage like /data/user/0/com.pkgname/filename.txt and rootbundle load files from assets that are package within the app like assets/img.png

Comment: As I know the only way to access assets of the root folder of the project, we need to use rootBundle. So a File object with that path is not existant.